# Using values in raster to extend a raster/polygon to contour/LiDAR value

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator, flood

I'm using ArcMap.

I have a raster of flood levels (LiDAR + a water depth).
I want to add 50mm onto the flood level raster which I can do with raster calculator.
But then what I want to do is 'extend' the flood level raster out to the same level in the LiDAR

e.g. my flood level is 10m and the flood extent is 5m wide. I then add 50mm to the flood level and the LiDAR shows that a flood level of 10.05m would then be 5.5m wide.

How can I extend the raster flood levels to the corresponding LiDAR level?

I don't need the level values in the end output, just the flood extent so I can convert to polygon or whatever else.

Comment: Google says https://www.google.com/search?q=flood+modelling+in+arcgis&rlz=1C1GCEA_enAU1030AU1030&oq=flood+modelling+in+arcgis - flood modelling is not a simple concept, it's not as easy as just adding a few cm.

Comment: Try flow distance (vertical) to existing flood as 'streams'. Extension is where output is less or equal to 0.05m. Might work if flood depth at the edges is close to 0. Otherwise  search this site for 'flood'